# How do I duplicate the same window in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ursina

I tried duplicating a the same window but it just went. I made this `server.py` file that needs to be run twice if we need 2 players. Anyone know how to duplicate windows in vscode?

Comment: You can also try to open another terminal

Comment: please consider putting some screenshots and code snippets. That way, your problem becomes clearer. Usually the more information makes users respond faster.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in detail? What means `duplicate the same window`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open up a new terminal window with `cntrl + shift + backtick`, and run your python server there (probably on a different port).